# How to make a START/STOP button for an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

just wondering how to make a button "START" that when pressed triggers a function and the text changes to "STOP". then when pressed again the function will stop and the text changes back to "START"

Ive got the button already that starts the function. and i can handle changing the title, just not sure on what to use to make the 1 button have 2 functions

Comment: You might wanna read up about if-statements: http://cupsofcocoa.com/2010/11/11/extension-4-what-goes-inside-the-if-statement/ , http://cupsofcocoa.com/2010/11/10/objective-c-lesson-4-if-statements-and-booleans/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the IBAction method like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *btn = (UIbutton *)sender;
  NSString *title=btn.titleLabel.text; 
  if ([title isEqualToString:@"Start"])
  {
   //Start 
  }else
  {
   //Stop
  }
}
```

Comment: No issues. Thank you that was exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 - (IBAction) buttonAction:(id)sender
  {
    if([[(UIButton *)sender currentTitle]isEqualToString:@"START"])
   {

    [actionButton setTitle:@"STOP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //start the action here and change the button text to STOP
   }
   else if([[(UIButton *)sender currentTitle]isEqualToString:@"STOP"]) 
   {

    [actionButton setTitle:@"START" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     //stop the action here and change the button text to START
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have at least two options here:

1. Check for the title of your button and depending on the value call an action or the other.
2. Create two different buttons, each one with his action and show/hide them.